# How can I get a list of all installed extensions in a VS Code extension for the web?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to get all installed extensions from my extension but I'm not able to get web extensions from list.

The way I'm listing using vscode extension api:

```js
vscode.extensions.all
```

The command line doesn't list as well.

```
code --list-extensions
```

One web extension example is vscodevim: https://open-vsx.org/vscode/item?itemName=vscodevim.vim

Web Extension reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/web-extensions#web-extension-enablement

using `vscode.extensions.all` and command line `code --list-extensions` doesn't list web extensions.